# Creating guest users in Azure AD with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to create a guest user with Microsoft Graph API. I used the property `UserType`.

```
user.UserType =  "Guest";
```

But the response shows `Invalid User principal Name`.

I am able to create the same user in portal.

Comment: There isn't enough here to go on. How are you authenticating? What SDK are you using? What did you use for the `userPrincipalName`?

Answer (score 8):

To add a external user to the organization, we need to use the invitation REST instead of create a user directly. Here is the REST and code sample(Microsoft Graph SDK) for your reference:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 551

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

Code Sample:

```
string accessToken = "";
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
       (requestMessage) =>
      {
          requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

          return Task.FromResult(0);
 }));

Invitation invitation = new Invitation();
invitation.SendInvitationMessage = true;
invitation.InvitedUserEmailAddress = "xxxx@hotmail.com";
invitation.InviteRedirectUrl = "http://localhost";
var result= graphserviceClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation).Result;
```